# Arduino + GSM SIM900 returns ÿ char

Tags: c, arduino, serial-port, gsm

So, when I send at example "AT" via Serial, GSM always returns me ÿ char. "AT" returns ÿÿ - any one char returns one ÿ. Where is the problem? Maybe connection is wrong? Should I use any resistors and connect GSM TX also to the GND?

UPDATE: GSM responds only on CR and NL giving ÿ of each. Any ideas?

Code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#define rx 10
#define tx 11
SoftwareSerial gsm(rx, tx);

void setup()  
{
   Serial.begin(9600);
   gsm.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{ 
    if(gsm.available())
       Serial.write(gsm.read());

    if(Serial.available())
       gsm.write(Serial.read());
}
```

Interfacing:

[image: Interfacing]

Comment: Do the GSM indicator LED's light up properly?  Have you tried other AT commands like: `ATI`?  Some random googling led me to this: https://code.google.com/p/gsm-shield-arduino/downloads/list which may be helpful once you get communication with the module working.

Comment: I need to make sure that I've properly connected pins.

Comment: Do you have a datasheet?  I can't seem to find one for that particular board.  I believe the ATMega328/168 have internal pull-up resistors and pull-down resistors depending on which port you're using ... but you are communicating with the GSM module via UART so I doubt you'll need them.

Comment: It's impossible to find datasheet. Anyway, that board has low voltage TTL - 3.3V. Maybe here is problem?

Comment: That `ÿ` character is 0xFF in hexadecimal.

Comment: Could it be effect of fried gsm board?

Comment: Regarding "GSM responds only on CR and NL giving ÿ of each. Any ideas?", this is by specification and the correct thing. AT command lines should always be terminated by <CR> (only) and nothing else. See V.250 (http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-V.250-200307-I/en) for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was in the power supply. There must be at least 2 ampers.

Comment: I had nearly the same problem. In my approach I used a mobile phone power supply (5.14V / 2A) and it didn't connect. Then I used a laboratory power supply unit and adjusted the same value and limited the current to 2A and it worked. On the oscilloscope I saw small spikes (50Hz). An attached capacitor (~470µA) should solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your baud rate is incorrect. Have you tried 19200? Documentation from other SIM900 based boards show the default at 19200.